# keycloak: notification after max login failure

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

After a user has failed to log in too many times in too short a time, is there a way to have the Keycloak login screen tell the user that they are temporarily locked, so they can know they have to wait and try again later?

At the moment, it continues to tell them their password is wrong, so they will probably keep trying, and may end up being told their correct password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak provides you the possibility to define custom messages and to provide a custom theme where you can overwrite certain views and messages as well as provide messages for other languages.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes

### Custom message key

You can modify the message key *'invalidUserMessage'* which is the message shown when the user is locked. It defaults to *'Invalid username or password'*.

We do it by providing a custom theme for the login type, but you can modify the message key provided by the keycloak installation at *'keycloak/themes/base/login/messages/messages_en.properties'*.

### Custom view

When you provide a custom *login-password.ftl* or *login.ftl*, depends on what you use, then you could check for the message during the rendering, and conditionally render a part which is only shown when the user is locked.

```
<#assign userLocked = message?? && message.summary == msg("invalidUserMessage")>
<#if section = "header" && !userLocked >...<#/if>
```

For instance, we use it in javascript to disable all inputs when we see that the user is locked along with displaying the modified message to the user.

```
<script>
        const serverFieldErrors = {
            "password": "${(message.summary)!""}"
        }
        if (serverFieldErrors.password === "${msg('invalidUserMessage')}") {
            document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((element) => element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"));
        }
    </script>
```

To my knowledge, keycloak provides no other way to handle such a use case.